# Cast to typeof(self)

Tags: swift

Is it possible to make a category (extension) that would eventually return an object casted to `instancetype`? I have a category to loads SKS files but since this category is for `SKNode` then all other subclasses like `SKScene` or `SKEmitterNode`, etc.. will adopt it too.

So I would simply like to avoid always casting from `SKNode` to `instancetype`. Is it possible to change return type to `instancetype` and make sure that compiler is happy with return value?

I think I can use `-> Self` as return type but then I have no idea how to cast `scene` to instancetype so this thing would compile..

For example:

`SKEmitterNode.unarchiveFromFile("Blah")` would return an instance of `SKEmitterNode`

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file: String) -> SKNode {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks")
        var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)

        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
        unarchiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")

        let scene = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKNode
        unarchiver.finishDecoding()

        return scene
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you change `-> SKNode` to `-> Self` and `as SKNode` to `as Self`?

Comment: I can change SKNode to Self in definition but I cannot cast `scene` to Self in the end. You probably had the same issue with instancetype in objc :)

Comment: Right; in Objective-C you'd use `self` in a class method, or `[self class]` in an instance method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This might work for you. I could not test it because I have not much experience with
SpriteKit. But it does compile and the compiler inferred type for

```
let e = SKEmitterNode.unarchiveFromFile("Blah")
```

is SKEmitterNode. The idea is to define a generic helper function

```
func unarchiveFromFileHelper<T where T : SKNode>(file: String) -> T
```

so that

```
class func unarchiveFromFile(file: String) -> Self {
    // define helper function ...
    return unarchiveFromFileHelper(file)
}
```

calls the helper function with `T == Self`.

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file: String) -> Self {

        func unarchiveFromFileHelper<T where T : SKNode>(file: String) -> T {
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks")
            var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)

            let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
            unarchiver.setClass(T.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")

            let scene = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as T
            unarchiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        }

        return unarchiveFromFileHelper(file)
    }
}
```

**Update:** If you are targeting iOS 8/OS X 10.10 or later then there
is no need for a custom unarchive method anymore. As noted in
[Cannot use unarchiveFromFile to set GameScene in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098884/cannot-use-unarchivefromfile-to-set-gamescene-in-spritekit), you can use

```
convenience init?(fileNamed filename: String)
```

from the `SKNode` superclass, e.g.

```
if let e = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Blah") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: While this code is valid, swift compiler simply crashed with seg fault in release build :)

Comment: But moving inner function outside as private class function solves the problem.