# Custom SKSpriteNode subclass from SKNode extension unarchiveFromFile()

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, nskeyedunarchiver

Is there any way to unarchive a custom `SKSpriteNode` subclass from a SpriteKit Scene File (the one that ends `*.sks`)? I am using the `SKNode` extension `unarchiveFromFile(file)` which returns a scene that I am then copying the `SKSpriteNode` I need out of.

I could inside my custom `SKSpriteNode` subclass unarchive the sprite from the `*.sks` file and then copy over the data I need (i.e. `SKTexture`, size, position, `SKPhysicsBody` etc.) in the init. I guess I could also make an `SKNode` subclass wrapper and assign the sprite from the archive to a sprite property, I am just curious if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Is this related to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271208/cast-to-typeofself ?

Comment: This is related but I was more asking about being able to unarchive an SKSpriteNode subclass from an *.sks file. I believe you can't do this currently, there are workarounds by replacing classes in the unarchiver but thats a little bit over kill for what I am after. I think my best option is to use SKNode markers in the *.sks file and then replace them as I unarchive. Thank you for your comment, much appreciated.