# Cannot use unarchiveFromFile to set GameScene in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode7-beta2

I'm using Xcode 7 beta 2 and following raywenderlich.com's Breakout tutorial to learn SpriteKit. Here's the error I get when I try to load GameScene using unarchiveFromFile.

> GameScene.type does not have a member named unarchiveFromFile.

Here's the code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // 1. Create local variables for two physics bodies
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    // 2. Assign the two physics bodies so that the one with the lower category is always stored in firstBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    // 3. react to the contact between ball and bottom
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == BallCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BottomCategory {
        //TODO: Replace the log statement with display of Game Over Scene

        if let mainView = view {
            let gameOverScene = GameOverScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameOverScene") as! GameOverScene
            gameOverScene.gameWon = false
            mainView.presentScene(gameOverScene)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `class func unarchiveFromFile` is defined in a custom `extension SKNode` in GameViewController.swift of the sample project. Did you convert the project to "Last Swift syntax" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `init(fileNamed:)` initialiser, which is available from iOS 8 onwards. For example:

```
if let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene") {
    // ...
}
```

It's important to note that `init(fileNamed:)` is a convenience initialiser on [`SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKNode/nodeWithFileNamed:):

```
convenience init?(fileNamed filename: String)
```

Therefore, for `GameOverScene` to automatically inherit `init(fileNamed:)`,   `GameOverScene` must adhere to the following rules from *[The Swift Programming Language: Initialisation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)* (rule 2 especially):

> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> **Rule 1** If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
> automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2** If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its
> superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per
> rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its
> definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass
> convenience initializers.

Comment: There is a unarchiveFromFile method in Ray Wenderlich's sample project which uses NSKeyedUnarchiver to instantiate a (subclass) instance of SKNode from a .sks file, and that worked without problem with Xcode 7 in my quick test.

Comment: In that case there's something else wrong with the OP's code and so my answer doesn't address the *actual* problem. However, `unarchiveFromFile` no longer seems to be used; it's not included in the default Sprite Kit project and `init(fileNamed: "...")` is used instead.

Comment: You are right, `init(fileNamed:)` was added in the iOS 8 SDK, so this would be the better solution if your deployment target is iOS 8 (or later). However, the original problem is still unclear to me, I could download the sample project and convert it to Swift 2 with a few clicks :)

Comment: And what is the analog for init(fileNamed:) in Objective-C?