# How do I get my unarchiveFromFile function to work?

Tags: ios, swift, return, sknode

The unarchiveFromFile function does not work in the case below. I am having an error that says:

"Missing return in a function expected to return 'SKNode?'

Not sure what the problem is, as this function was working before I updated XCode to version 7.2.

```
extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {

        do {
            let sceneData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)

        let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData:sceneData)
        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKNode
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }


    } else {
        return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `init(fileNamed:)`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098884/cannot-use-unarchivefromfile-to-set-gamescene-in-spritekit.

Comment: put `return nil` in your catch block after print statement

Comment: The `catch` block has no return value.

Comment: you have to return inside your if block, and if it enters catch block, then no value is returned...this is why you get the error

Comment: return the scene as the last line of the if block..this should clear the error

Comment: Try finding the correct version of this unarchiveFromFile function on the internet, for swift. I just copied and pasted it, and using it as it is.